# Browser gets forced closed after execution in watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir-webdriver, child-process

After executing test case in ruby-watir-cucumber, my browser is getting automatically closed. I am not using any @browser.close in my code.

I am unable to find anything on this issue.

Below is my gem env

```
   D:\Users\zzuj001>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [i386-mingw32]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: D:/Users/zzuj001/.gem/specs
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86-mingw32
- GEM PATHS:
  - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - D:/Users/zzuj001/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
   - http://gems.github.com
- SHELL PATH:
   - C:\Ruby200\bin
   - C:\Ruby200\bin
   - C:\Windows\system32
   - C:\Windows
   - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
   - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
   - c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
   - c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
   - c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
```

Comment: Is there an exception when it occurs? It would also help if you could share the code that you are using.

Comment: No there is no exception, a scenario is getting passed. And this is not for some particular code. It is happening for each code i am executing with watir.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any 'After' or 'at_exit' code blocks in your env.rb file?